# Can't uninstall Python 3.10 from Windows on USB stick

Tags: python, windows, installation

I want to completely uninstall Python from my laptop. But when I try to do it normally through the setup it doesn't work.
[image]

I think it is because I installed Python on a USB stick. And the computer thinks that the USB E:/ drive is the correct one.
Since I was overwhelmed with the situation, I tried to uninstall Python as soon as possible. But without success. I have uninstalled the "python.exe", which of course does not install everything. But now I have nothing and do not know how to uninstall Python.
If more details are needed please write. I do not know exactly what everything could be important.

Other screenshots:

[image: Program]

Setup:

[image: Setup]

Try to repair:

[image: Try to repair]

When I try to change with setup:

[image: Modify]

Comment: Have you tried running the uninstaller with the USB stick plugged in?

Comment: By the way, you forgot to translate the sentence just before the last screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

First check if your windows7 or above because this version of python you want install work with windows7 and above.

try to download in drive (C:/) then add the path to Environment Variables follow this link:
https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/

Answer (score 0):

Ich habe Python von meinem USB-Stick deinstalliert und den USB-Stick entfernt.  Dann habe ich Python neu installiert.  Tatsächlich hatte ich Python bereits installiert.  Aber jetzt funktioniert es, danke.